# rspec with --tag option runs different test than spring rspec with same --tag option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

When I run

```
spring rspec --tag ~slow
```

None of my tests are run and I see this unexpected output:

```
Run options:
  include {:focus=>true}
  exclude {:slow=>true}

All examples were filtered out; ignoring {:focus=>true}

All examples were filtered out

Finished in 0.21728 seconds (files took 0.43359 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures
```

When I run:

```
rspec --tag ~slow
```

I see the following expected set of tests run:

```
Run options:
  include {:focus=>true}
  exclude {:slow=>true}

All examples were filtered out; ignoring {:focus=>true}

.
. testing output remove for berevity
.


Finished in 6.9 seconds (files took 15.29 seconds to load)
179 examples, 0 failures, 4 pending
```

Is this a problem I can fix or, if I want to use spring, do I have to give up using --tags ?

TL;DR: Seems I have to pick between saving time using Spring or saving time skipping slow rspec tests.  Can't get both.

ADDENDUM:
Submitted Spring issue here: https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/359

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This now works:

```
  time spring rspec ./spec --tag speed:slow  
  time spring rspec ./spec --tag ~speed:slow
```

Seems adding "./spec" was the necessary change.

Using:
  * spring (1.2.0)
  * spring-commands-rspec (1.0.2)
  * rspec-collection_matchers (1.0.0)
  * rspec-core (3.0.4)
  * rspec-expectations (3.0.4)
  * rspec-mocks (3.0.4)
  * rspec-rails (3.0.2)
  * rspec-support (3.0.4)